# Drupal- Link two content types by mutual value

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have two content types: `man` and `food`;

The `man` content type contains the man's name several more fields and a unique id field created by the serial module.

The second content type is created by the users via an external form. The results from the form are set as the `food` content type. One of the fields is equal to the unique id field at the `man` content type.

**My question is:** 
I want to create a view that will show me all the `man` values, But when the value is clicked, it will lead me to a table that contains all the `food` content type entries where the unique id in `food` is equal to the `man` unique id value.

It so easy to do this in php but I am new to drupal.

Any help of lead will be great.

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about 2 different things (pages). Creating any of them isn't much of the problem, but you have to be more precise with your question.

Basically, create first view which will just list all the users. It will have link to second one with user id as parameter it passes.

Create second view which will list all food nodes and add to it contextual filter for user id reference field and output will be narrowed only to food that is referencing user which id is passed.